# Imprimir item de uma fila removendo cada item da mesma

Tags: c, ponteiro, fila, printf

Estou fazendo um programa que recebe uma string com palavras separadas por virgula que separa essas palavras e as enfileiram (Até ai consegui fazer tranquilo), depois o programa tem que ir removendo e imprimindo os itens, mas não consigo desenvolver a função desenfileira, tentei até me basear em outros códigos de livros.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct fila {
        char nome [30];
        char dado;
        struct fila *proximoPtr;    
    };
    typedef struct fila Fila;
    typedef Fila *PtrFila;
    void imprimeFila (PtrFila atualPtr);
    int ehVazia(PtrFila headPtr );
    //void dequeue(PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr );
    void enqueue(PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr, char nome[30]);

    int main(){
            PtrFila headPtr = NULL;
            PtrFila tailPtr = NULL;
        for ( ; ; ){
            char linha[1024];
            puts("Escreva Nomes Separados por Virgula");
            fgets(linha, 1024 , stdin);
            char item;
            char* tok;
            char* tmp = strdup(linha);

            tok=strtok(tmp, ",");
            int cont=0;
            while (tok != NULL) {
                cont++;
                enqueue( &headPtr, &tailPtr, tok);

                tok = strtok (NULL, ",");
            }
            imprimeFila(headPtr);
            //dequeue (&headPtr, &tailPtr); A função que não está funcionando

        }
    }
    /*void dequeue(PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr ) {
        char aux;
        PtrFila tempPtr;

        aux = ( *headPtr )->aux;
        tempPtr = *headPtr; 
        *headPtr = ( *headPtr )->proximoPtr; 

        if ( *headPtr == NULL ) {
            *tailPtr = NULL; 
        } 

        free( tempPtr );
        imprimeFila(headPtr);
    } */

    int ehVazia( PtrFila headPtr ){
        return headPtr == NULL;
    }

    void imprimeFila( PtrFila atualPtr ){
        PtrFila inicioPtr;
        inicioPtr=atualPtr;
        if ( atualPtr == NULL ) {
            puts( "Fila esta vazia.\n" );
        } 

            atualPtr=inicioPtr;
            while ( atualPtr != NULL ) {
                printf( "%s --> ", atualPtr->nome );
                atualPtr = atualPtr->proximoPtr;
            } 

            puts( "NULL\n" );

        } 

    void enqueue( PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr, char nome[30]){

        char * novalinha = strchr(nome, '\n');
        if (novalinha)
            *novalinha = '\0';  

        PtrFila newPtr; 
        newPtr=malloc(sizeof(Fila));

        if ( newPtr != NULL ) { 
            newPtr->dado = nome;
            newPtr->proximoPtr = NULL;

            strcpy( newPtr->nome,nome);


            if ( ehVazia( *headPtr ) ) {
                *headPtr = newPtr;
            } 
            else {
                ( *tailPtr )->proximoPtr = newPtr;
            } 

            *tailPtr = newPtr;
        } 
        else {
            printf( "%c nao foi inserido. Memoria nao foi disponibilizada.\n");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Não precisa escrever o titulo em caixa alta. PARECE QUE VC ESTA GRITANDO COM TODOS AQUI!

Comment: Faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais sobre o site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente, para uma fila, eu recomendaria criar uma `struct` contendo os dois ponteiros `inicioPtr` e `fimPtr` para não ter que ficar passando referências para as suas variáveis locais; de fato, os problemas na `dequeue()` todos têm a ver com erros de tipo entre tipos base e seus ponteiros. Mas vejamos:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Em primeiro lugar, você esqueceu de incluir o cabeçalho `<string.h>` para usar `strdup()` e `strcpy()`. Isso funciona, porque as funções não usam tipos de dados definidos no cabeçalho, mas é um mau hábito. Você deve ter tomado uns avisos na hora de compilar reclamando disso: por favor procure ler e analisar as mensagens do compilador quando você compilar o seu programa.

```
struct fila {
    char nome [30];
    char * dado;
    struct fila *proximoPtr;    
};
typedef struct fila Fila;
typedef Fila *PtrFila;
```

Na sua fila, você tem um membro `nome` de tipo `char[30]` e um membro `dado` de tipo `char`. Mais tarde, na `enqueue()`, você vai pegar o nome passado como parâmetro e copiá-lo para o vetor `nome` *e* assinalar uma referência a ele no campo `dado`, que não o comporta porque ele é um `char`. Então eu o alterei para `char *`, um ponteiro para `char`, embora não fique claro por que você quer uma referência se já copiou o nome.

```
void dequeue(PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr ) {
    PtrFila tempPtr;

    if (*headPtr == NULL) return;
    tempPtr = *headPtr; 
    *headPtr = ( *headPtr )->proximoPtr; 

    if ( *headPtr == NULL ) {
        *tailPtr = NULL; 
    } 

    free( tempPtr );
    imprimeFila(*headPtr);
}
```

A `dequeue()` propriamente dita é simples. Você cria uma variável `aux` de tipo `char` e assinala a ela um membro não-existente `aux` da fila, que quase certamente é o `dado` que você renomeou e esqueceu de refatorar. Mas também depois não faz nada com essa variável, então eu a removi completamente.

Além disso, lá no final, você estava passando `headPtr`, que é um `ptrFila *`, em vez de `*headPtr`, que é um `ptrFila` conforme a função `imprimeFila()` pede. É por essa razão que eu, pessoalmente, não gosto de criar sinônimos do estilo `ptrX` para `X*`. Porém, não é uma regra de ferro; tem gente que gosta e não se enrola com isso.

Finalmente, na `enqueue()` temos dois problemas:

```
void enqueue( PtrFila *headPtr, PtrFila *tailPtr, char nome[30]){

    char * novalinha = strchr(nome, '\n');
    if (novalinha)
        *novalinha = '\0';  

    PtrFila newPtr; 
    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(Fila));

    if ( newPtr != NULL ) { 
        newPtr->dado = nome;
        newPtr->proximoPtr = NULL;

        strncpy( newPtr->nome,nome,30);


        if ( ehVazia( *headPtr ) ) {
            *headPtr = newPtr;
        } 
        else {
            ( *tailPtr )->proximoPtr = newPtr;
        } 

        *tailPtr = newPtr;
    } 
    else {
        printf( "%c nao foi inserido. Memoria nao foi disponibilizada.\n");
    } 
}
```

Em primeiro lugar, você escreve `strcpy( newPtr->nome,nome);`. Mas o que acontece se o usuário digitar um nome com mais de vinte e nove caracteres? Essa é uma classe de *bugs* que já causou muito dano por aí, os chamados *buffer overflows*. Prefira sempre usar funções, como a `strncpy()`, que recebem o tamanho do *buffer* de saída como parâmetro. Para qualquer função que você pensar da biblioteca padrão, existe uma versão com `n` no nome que recebe um parâmetro extra com o número máximo de caracteres a ler ou escrever. `stncpy()`, `strncmp()`, `snprintf()`, por aí vai.

Crie esse hábito de verificar a quantidade de caracteres que você está escrevendo, *triplamente* se o que você está escrevendo vier do usuário. Mais cedo ou mais tarde, alguém vai escrever algo que não deve e o seu *software* se arrebenta...

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Explicação perfeita. Só ajustei depois como ia querer e funcionou corretamente.